# Can I use this power supply?

Tags: power-supply

This may (and probably will) sound very silly, but I rather ask first than destroy my childhood memories - I found my old sega mega drive at my parents home, but it had no psu. I knew I had some psu's laying around at home so I found one that supplies 5V2A, but the console requires 10V1A.

I guess I should get an universal psu somewhere, but maybe, by some chance, the one I got at home won't burn my console and will actually work?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: No, don't use that one!  You need to find a power supply that will match the voltage (10V), and can supply at least the necessary current (1A or greater).  Radio Shack has some selectable-output supplies with interchangeable plugs...

Comment: 10V is a bit of an oddball voltage to find though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, thought so!
@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah, my dad offered his universal one and it only had 9/12V.
Could I be reading it wrong? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmCvPoAB9RQTzVhMmthdTNnQzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: They almost certainly would have had a custom brick for it.

Comment: Please pay attention to the comment by @SpehroPefhany in Adam's answer.  It's important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bitsmack says, you need a power supply that can produce the same voltage and at least as much current. The most reliable way to get one is to buy an old Sega AC adapter off of eBay. Sega Retro has [a page](http://segaretro.org/AC_adaptor) listing the adapters that work with various Sega consoles.

Comment: Note carefully that you must have one with the center pin NEGATIVE, according to Adam's link. That is relatively uncommon these days. If you connect the wrong polarity of adapter, even if everything else is okay, would likely damage the Sega device or blow an internal fuse.